# trouble converting jQuery ajax to plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm working on converting a jQuery ajax request into plain JavaScript just so I know how to do it both ways. What I'm trying to do is pass a JSON object from my PHP script into my JavaScript file and display the values of the JSON object on the page.

I'm just beginning to dive into AJAX and I've gotten the jQuery version to work on my own easily enough, but I'm having difficult with the plain JavaScript version. For the plain JavaScript part, I'm following along with a JavaScript book that I have. That's why the code structure may seem different.

Also, I'm aware there are no real security implementations and that is fine. This is just for my own learning purposes.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <h3>Grab the location of a person in the database below</h3>
    <form action="ajax/name.php" method="POST" name="ajaxForm" id="ajaxForm">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        <input type="submit" id="name-submit" name="name-submit" value="Grab">
    </form>

    <div id="results">
        <label for="location">Location: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name-data" id="name-data" disabled>
    </div>

    <div id="insert">
        <h3>Insert a new person with a new location below</h3>
        <form action="ajax/name.php" method="POST" name="insForm" id="insForm">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="ins-name" id="ins-name">
            <label for="location">Location: </label>
                <input type="text" name="ins-location" id="ins-location">
                <input type="submit" id="ins-submit" name="ins-submit" value="Insert">
        </form>
        <div id="insresults_name"></div>
        <div id="insresults_loc"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my jQuery code that works fine:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
var locForm = $('#ajaxForm');
var insForm = $('#insForm');

locForm.submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: locForm.attr('action'),
        data: locForm.serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#name-data').val(response);
        }
    });

    return false;
});

insForm.submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: insForm.attr('action'),
        data: insForm.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#insresults_name').text('Name: ' + response[0]);
            $('#insresults_loc').text('Location: ' + response[1]);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

Here is my PHP Script:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    require '../db/connect.php';
    $conn = new Con();
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM names WHERE name=:name');
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo (isset($result['location'])) ? $result['location'] : 'That name isn\'t listed';
}

if (isset($_POST['ins-name']) && isset($_POST['ins-location'])) {
    require '../db/connect.php';
    $conn = new Con();
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ins-name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $loc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ins-location', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO names (name, location) VALUES (:name, :loc)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':loc', $loc);

    try {
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM names WHERE name=:name');
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
            $stmt->execute();

            $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $val = array();
            $val[0] = $res['name'];
            $val[1] = $res['location'];

            echo json_encode($val);
        } else {
            echo 'Fail';
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '';
    }

}

?>
```

And here is the plain JavaScript that I've come up with, but doesn't work:

```
function getData() {
    'use strict';
    var name = document.getElementById('ins-name').value();
    var location = document.getElementById('ins-location').value();
    var url = document.getElementById('ins-name').getAttribute('action');
    if ((name.length > 0) && (location.length > 0)) {
        var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();
        ajax.ononreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
                // Check the status code:
                if ((ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 300) || (ajax.status == 304)) {
                    // if ajax.responseText isn't empty
                    if (ajax.responseText) {
                        var arr = Array();
                        arr = JSON.parse(responseText);
                        document.getElementById('insresults_name').innerHTML('Name: ' + arr[0]);
                        document.getElementById('insresults_loc').innerHTML('Location: ' + arr[1]);
                    } else {
                        alert('Something went wrong!');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Bad Status Code!');
                }
            }
        };
        ajax.open('POST', '../ajax/name.php', true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var data = 'name=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + 'location=' + encodeURIComponent(location);
        ajax.send(data);
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Please complete the form!');
    }
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        var form = document.getElementById('insForm');
        form.onsubmit = getData;
    }
}
window.onload(init);
```

Comment: Typo here: `ajax.ononreadystatechange` should be `ajax.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: Even after changing that, it still sends me to the action page. what I'm trying to do is get the results to display in those two divs below the form.

Comment: If it's changing pages, then you probably need to `preventDefault()` on the default form action from the onsubmit handler.

Comment: That's what I put the    return false; there for

Comment: Are you seeing any script errors?  Have you set breakpoints or inserted `console.log()` statements to see what happens with the flow through `getData()`.  Do you know if the request even gets to your server?  Basically, have you taken basic debugging and troubleshooting steps.  If you have, please post what you've seen.  If you haven't then that should always be the first steps when things don't work.

Comment: Oddly, when I get rid of 'use strict'; inside of the getData(), it works fine. Any clues as to why?